# How to catch a pywin32com exception on opening files

Tags: python, winapi, excel, com, custom-exceptions

I am trying to open an excel file in python using COM, and trying to catch the file not found error:

I first tried catching the IOError:

```
try:
   output = xl.Workbooks.Open(Params.workbookName)
except IOError as reason:
   print reason
   exit()
```

But COM doesn't raise an IO Error when it has a file not found problem, instead it raises something called com_error:

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception
>   occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office
>   Excel', u"'asdf.xlsx' could not be
>   found. Check the spelling of the file
>   name, and verify that the file
>   location is correct.\n\nIf you are
>   trying to open the file from your list
>   of most recently used files, make sure
>   that the file has not been renamed,
>   moved, or deleted.", u'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM',
>   0, -2146827284), None)

so logically I tried this:

```
try:
   output = xl.Workbooks.Open(Params.workbookName)
except com_error as reason:
   print reason
   exit()
```

but...

```
NameError: global name 'ComError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from pythoncom import com_error
```

and catch it in your `except` block

Comment: hi @inspectorG4dget  whats the difference between from pythoncom import com_error and from pywintypes import com_error. my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516209/difference-between-pywintypes-and-pythoncom-for-com-error