# How to catch these exceptions individually?

Tags: python, exception, quickbooks

I am writing a Python program that interfaces with Quickbooks. When connecting to Quickbooks, depending on the problem, I might get one of two common exceptions:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor.2', 'The QuickBooks company data file is currently open in a mode other than the one specified by your application.', None, 0, -2147220464), None)

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor.2', 'Could not start QuickBooks.', None, 0, -2147220472), None)
```

Catching the generic exception with `except Exception as e` shows that the type of `e` is `<class 'pywintypes.com_error'>`, which cannot be used to catch an exception:

```
... catch pywintypes.com_error as e:
NameError: global name 'pywintypes' is not defined
```

**So how might I catch these two exceptions in a non-generic manner?** Ideally the code would have this layout:

```
try:
    qb = qbsdk_interface.Qbsdk_Interface(QB_FILE)

except QbWrongModeError as e:
    print('Quickbooks is open in the wrong mode!')

except QbClosedError as e:
    print('Quickbooks is closed!')

except Exception as e:
    print('Something else went wrong!')
```

Of course, the exceptions `QbWrongModeError` and `QbClosedError` do not exist, so what should be there in their place?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203336/python-pythoncom-com-error-handling-in-python-3-2-2

Comment: Yes, it certainly is. Another similar one cam up in the Related links on the right as well. Figures: half an hour searching and I find nothing, and even the suggestions based on title came up with nothing while I was writing the question. But the Related sidebar finds them right away!

Answer (score 20):

As soon as I posted I found the way to catch the exception in a non-generic manner in a [question that appeared in the Related sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336831/how-to-catch-a-pywin32com-exception-on-opening-files). Here is the way to capture these exceptions:

```
from pywintypes import com_error

except com_error as e:
```

Note that the differing reasons for the exception cannot be handled individually, so the return code must be examined inside the `except` clause by comparing the value of `e.exceptinfo[5]`:

```
except com_error as e:

    if e.excepinfo[5] == -2147220464:
        print('Please change the Quickbooks mode to Multi-user Mode.')

    elif e.excepinfo[5] == -2147220472:
        print('Please start Quickbooks.')

    else:
        raise e
```

I had considered marking this question as a dupe, but considering that none of the other related questions handle the situation of **distinguishing between the different exceptions thrown** under this single type, I leave this one as it addresses this issue and answers it.

Comment: `e.excepinfo` doesn't have the return code in some versions of `pywintypes`, but `e.hresult` does.

Comment: @AlexM It seems that my com_errors do not have hresult. I get an AttributeError.

Comment: Exactly. We're using different versions of `pwintypes`, and my comment is there to help people no matter which version they have.

Answer (score 15):

Now `pywintypes.error` is `BaseException`.

There is no need to `from pywintypes import com_error`.

If you want to catch this exception.
You can just catch `BaseException`

```
except BaseException as e: # to catch pywintypes.error
    print(e.args)
```

the exception's format likes this:

```
(0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')
```

So If you want to examine the return code,use `e.args[0]` instead of `e.exceptinfo[5]`

Comment: This worked for me.  But why??  How did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add something to [@jizhihaoSAMA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075942/4980062) from [@dotancohen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053903/4980062) for added clarity.

You may want to raise any other errors that you're not expecting when catching a specific BaseException. Otherwise the code will just finish but not do what you're expecting.

```
except BaseException as e:  # to catch pywintypes.error
    if e.args[0] == -2147352567:
        print(my_str)
    else:
        raise e
```