# How to determine correct exception class

Tags: python, wmi

I'm using Python WMI module to collect hardware information from a Windows system.  This line raises an exception:

```
numa = c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wmi.py", line 1209, in __getattr__
  File "wmi.py", line 1220, in _cached_classes
  File "<COMObject winmgmts:>", line 3, in Get
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemServicesEx', None, None, 0, -1073738817), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "health_check.py", line 1138, in <module>
  File "health_check.py", line 1121, in main
  File "health_check.py", line 228, in hardware_info
  File "wmi.py", line 1211, in __getattr__
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
AttributeError: winmgmts:.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory
```

So I tried to catch it like this:

```
import pywintypes.com_error
try:
    numa = c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory()

except pywintypes.com_error:
    logger.error('Failed to read NUMA status.')
```

But the import fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "health_check.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes.com_error'; 'pywintypes' is not a package
[9464] Failed to execute script health_check
```

I tried not importing the `com_error` class but that didn't work either.  How can I find out the correct import to catch this type of exception?  After importing `wmi` the module exists here:

```
>>> sys.modules['pywintypes']
<module 'pywintypes' (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\pywintypes37.dll)>
>>> sys.modules['pywintypes'].com_error
<class 'pywintypes.com_error'>
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with using the correct or incorrect exception class. Import the module: `import pywintypes`. You can't specify a non-module in `import thing.whatever`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch these exceptions individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053785/how-to-catch-these-exceptions-individually)

Comment: I tried that; it doesn't catch the exception

Comment: @fooiey very helpfu, thanks!  `BaseException` works.  But the heart of my question is how can you figure this out, given a new (and possibly undocumented) module.  Is there some kind of introspection that will tell you the right exception class?

Comment: Maybe I've just answered my own question.  After catching `BaseException as e` it tells me it's an AttributeError so then I could use that.

Answer (score 0):

WMI package has the creation of it’s own exception type. It looks like it raises it in your example.

```
from wmi.wmi import x_wmi

try:
    numa = c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory()

except x_wmi:
    logger.error('Failed to read NUMA status.')
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: I just looked in their source code on the github - in the file wmi.py you can see the corresponding class