# difference between pywintypes and pythoncom for com_error

Tags: python, com, win32com

What is the difference between pywintypes and pythoncom? I am really new to COM handling using python so a simplified description will be helpful. also I am using a com wrapper to fixed the com error "call is rejected by callee". however the com error is not capture by the exception.

so should I be importing com_error from pywintypes or pythoncom?

```
from pywintypes import com_error
import win32com.client


class ComWrapper:

    @staticmethod
    def wrap(func, *func_args):
        try:
            print('running the function')
            return func(*func_args)

        except com_error as e:
            print('checking the error')
            if e.strerror == 'Call was rejected by callee.':
                print('com_error retrying ', e)
                time.sleep(5)
                wrap(func, *func_args)

            raise
```

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be the same, and both come from the [`win32com`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) module. You can see [in the sourcecode](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/com/pythoncom.py) that `pythoncom` imports `pywintypes`.

I believe the two names only exist for legacy reasons. [This Sourceforge message from 2003](https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/mailman/message/4275380/) by the `win32com` developers seems to shows they were merged to avoid duplicated code.